# CSS Image/Video Grid breaking

Tags: html, css, grid

i've been having issues with the image/video grid (similar to Instagram). It does have some Ajax like loading more contents on scroll (which is working fine) but the only problem I have which I couldn't seem to fix or find answers anywhere is the grid.

Before you answer, please note the following:

1. I am using a template called: [AdminLTE 3](https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/)
2. Template is powered in [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/)
3. I am using [CSS Instagram Grid Example](https://codepen.io/MAB015/pen/pZjYbX)
4. Using the latest jQuery (3.6.0)
5. [Here's a video on what I'm talking about and having issues with](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snkwvWiL_ts)

Alright, let's get started.

Here is the CSS Styles that I am using:

```
.uploads-wrapper
{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(100px, 293px));
    justify-content: center;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
.uploads-content-post
{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.uploads-content-post-image
{
    margin: 0;
}
.uploads-content-post-image img
{
    width:  100%;
    height: 293px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.uploads-content-post-overlay
{
    background: rgba(0,0,0, .4);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
.uploads-content-post:hover .uploads-content-post-overlay
{
    display: flex;
}

.uploads-content-post-like
{
    width: 80px;
    margin: 50%;
    font-size: 18px;
    font:100%;
    margin-left: 100px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 501px)
{
    .uploads-content-post-image img
    {
        width:    100%;
        height:   130px !important;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .uploads-content-post-like
    {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .uploads-content-post-like
    {
        font-size: 15px;
        font:auto;
        margin: 50% !important;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px)
{
    .uploads-content-post-image img
    {
        width:    100%;
        height:   140px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .uploads-content-post-like
    {
        font-size: 15px;
        font:auto;
        margin: 50% !important;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 601px)
{
    .uploads-content-post-image img
    {
        width:    100%;
        height:   180px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .uploads-content-post-like
    {
        font-size: 15px;
        font:auto;
        margin: 50% !important;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 758px)
{
    .uploads-content-post-like
    {
        margin: 50%;
    }
    .uploads-content-post-like
    {
        font-size: 15px;
        font:auto;
        margin: 50% !important;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
{
    .uploads-wrapper
    {
        grid-gap: 3px;
    }
    .uploads-content-post-image img
    {
        width:    100%;
        height:   220px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .uploads-content-post-like
    {
        font-size: 15px;
        margin: 50% !important;
        font:auto;
    }
}
```

[Picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqX7v.png)

What I've noticed is that the **.uploads-wrapper** seems to be the main problem here. I am using PHP as a server side programming language, and just before I call the PHP's "while loop" to fetch more uploads, i've placed this:

```
<section class="uploads-wrapper" style="margin-top:10px;">
```

So to put it simple, I don't want the grid to break in to blank column as you can see in the picture/video example. I want it to work like Instagram's grid (I know Instagram's is 3, but I prefer 4 since it fits well in AdminLTE 3 template).

If you require additional information please let me know. I'd like to learn what the issue is here and hopefully i'll be able to fight it in the future if an issue like that or something similar appears in the future or so. Thank you guys for your time answers.

EDIT: As @Ben Souchet mentioned, the code after `.uploads-wrapper` is as follows:

```
<div class="uploads-content-post">
    <a href="#">
        <figure class="uploads-content-post-image">
            <img alt src="example.jpg" class="img-fluid" decoding="auto" style="object-fit: cover;">
        </figure>
        <div class="uploads-media-type-icon-placeholder">
            <span class="uploads-media-type-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-heart"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
        <span class="uploads-content-post-overlay">
            <p>
              <span class="uploads-content-post-like">0</span>
            </p>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I also don't have a live website, it's in localhost.

Comment: if the website is live can we get the url to have an idea of the html layout, if not can you add in your post an exemple of how elements (html) are inside the `<section class="uploads-wrapper">` tags. By the way very good post formatting it's clear :)

Comment: I edited the post as you mentioned to provide code inside the .uploads-wrapper

Comment: When the ajax load more "posts" are you 100% sure you [append](https://api.jquery.com/append/) inside the `<section class="uploads-wrapper">` or you create a new `<section>`. Because it's seems to me that it can be the issue.

Comment: Hi Ben, i'll look into that right now and we'll let you know. :)

Comment: Hi Ben, so the issue was that `<section class="uploads-wrapper">` was done in an error. That is because I am loading these uploads to a div of `<div id="media-react"></div>` using Ajax. So I changed the `<style>.uploads-wrapper</style>` to `#media-react` and it worked perfectly. Thanks for your time, brother. Oh and thanks for feedback, means a lot to me :').

Comment: Your welcome :)